# Cascading IPropertyChanged

Tags: c#

I have a data structure organised as such:

A `List<Graphic>` containing a `List<Symbol>` which contains a `List<Alias>` amongst other things.

I want to be able to run a function within the `Graphic` class whenever anything changes within an alias/symbol/graphic. The best way that I can see to do this would be to implement `IPropertyChanged` on each of the three classes. However, is it possible to cascade these whilst getting a reference to the `Graphic` as to what exactly changed?

Note: The changes will generally be to the properties within an `Alias` but it is just as plausible that a `Symbol` could be removed/added or renamed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage class `ObservableCollection<T>` that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Basically, you need to create a derived class and override some methods

```
    public class Data
    {
        public ObservableCollection<String> InnerCollection { get; set; }
    }

    public class collection : ObservableCollection<Data>
    {
        protected override void InsertItem(int index, Data item)
        {
            item.InnerCollection.CollectionChanged += InnerCollection_CollectionChanged;
            base.InsertItem(index, item);
        }

        private void InnerCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Actually it does not make any sense. You may need to construct something special. But firing an event it would be enough
            OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }

        protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
        {
            var date = base.Items[index];
            date.InnerCollection.CollectionChanged -= InnerCollection_CollectionChanged;
            base.RemoveItem(index);
        }
    }
```

Using something like this, you can nest your events as deep as you want.

Comment: Cheers! That's exactly what I need.

Comment: You can also use BindingList<T> for a built in collection that does it.